VsCode Navigate through code on Emacs
I am Gnu/linux user and Emacs but at my job I have to use Windows and vscode for a Ts project. So I decided to use Emacs on my job laptop but I cannot navigate through the contollers/services on the job project. For example:
      '/v4/xmlCreateOrder...',
      (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        const controller = new DirectvCreateOrderController();
        req.body.webhookType = CommerceConstants.blaBla;
        req.body.onlyXml = true;
        controller.createOrderFromGenericPayment.bind(controller)(req, res);
      },
    );

So, on VsCode I use Control+click on createOrderFromGenericPayment and that takes me to another file where that method is defined. I really want to do that on Emacs(I don't know how to do that neither on my Fedora personal laptop nor my Windows jobs laptop).
That's is the question: how can I do that on Emacs?
I search different options like Avy, Helm, Projectile, Counsel but I don't know if that kind of thing can help me. Maybe they do but I am not sure.

See xref in the Emacs manual. It will need some setup depending on what backend you want to use.

but it show me the same problem:  TAGS

Yes, you will need to set up a TAGS file for your project (if you choose to go that way). See the docs.

Press M-., which runs xref-find-definitions. Traditionally xref looks in the project’s TAGS file, but other backends are available. If you set up LSP using either eglot or lsp-mode then there will be a backend that queries the LSP server instead. VsCode uses an LSP server for most languages, so if you configure Emacs to talk to the same server then you will get the same results from the query as it does.
